# How to diversify the result of top-hits aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, search-engine, elasticsearch-aggregation

Let's start with a concrete example. I have a document with these fields:

```
{
  "template": {
    "mappings": {
      "template": {
        "properties": {
          "tid": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "folder_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "status": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "major_num": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to aggregate the query result by field `folder_id`, and for each  group divided by `folder_id`, retrieve the top-N documents' `_source` detail. So i write query DSL like:

```
GET /template/template/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "status": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "folder": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "folder_id",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_hit":{
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 5,
            "_source": ["major_num"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, now comes a requirement that the top hits documents for each `folder_id` must be diversified on the field `major_num`. For each `folder_id`, the top hits documents retrieve by the sub `top_hits` aggregation under the `terms` aggregation, must be unique on field `major_num`, and for each `major_num` value, return at most 1 document in the sub top hits aggregation result.

`top_hits` aggregation cannot accept sub-aggregations, so how should i solve the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply adding another `terms` aggregation on the `major_num` field ?

```
GET /template/template/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "status": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "folder": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "folder_id",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "majornum": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "major_num",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "top_hit": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This will just return two same level aggregation result, one for the ```major_num``` terms and one for the ```top_hits``` result, however, the ```top_hits``` result documents are not "unique" for the field ```major_num```, but that's what i want.

Comment: What i want is, for example, under the same ```folder_id```, get 1 document for ```major_num == 1```, 1 document for ```major_num == 2```, and so on...

Comment: That's exactly what you'll get since each `major_num` will get its own bucket. Have you tried it out?